# Detect SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, registry, nsis

I've googled a day but the question is still question: how to detect SQL Server 2008 R2 on various Windows versions:

- via **registry** (would be our favorite solution),
- via **file system**,
- via installer **exit code**?

Installer developed with NSIS. Some additional informations:

**Registry**

Samples on the net are out of date or simply improper. Not just R2 but 2k8 detection is problematic too.

**File system**

I have no idea what files are especially from 2k8 R2.

**Installer exit code**

In some cases exits without error code (i.e. prerequisites missing).

Comment: thank you all! we need to integrate it into NSIS installer but I'll feedback after testing the solutions in different environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the WMI to listy all the microsoft product installed and then you could look foe the one you need

```
public static class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"]);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: a really cool and really slow solution - but I've decided to use this. SELECT @@VERSION is very smooth but SQL connection is needed.

Answer (score 2):

try to execute this query:

```
SELECT @@Version
```

I get this result back:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010
>   15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2  (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

is this enough? For me yes :)

Comment: What if the service isn't started? And how did you identify which instance to connect to in order to run the query?

Comment: @Aaron, got you, see my other answer

Answer (score 2):

Look at the older [SQLPing](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/Tools/FreeTools/tabid/65/Default.aspx) source code which has a variety of methods

Comment: +1 you need to check for all of the possible instances before you can think about checking what version they are.

Answer (score 1):

And before you try execute query provided by Davide (SELECT @@Version) you can check, that MSSQL service is running

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
var list = ServiceController.GetServices().ToList();
        if (list.Any(sc => sc.ServiceName.ToLower().Contains("mssql")))
```

Comment: You still need to identify the instance name(s) you need to connect to - as there may be more than one instance installed. Knowing that at least one service is started doesn't mean you'll magically know to connect to each instance individually and check @@VERSION.

Comment: Aaron, you have right, but if you even know instance name - I think that this metod is quicker to chceck if MSSQL is running and then do connect than do connect to server and wait for timeout if server is offline.

Comment: Well do you want fast or accurate? The point is that you'll need to know the version(s) of any instances installed, regardless of whether they're currently running.

Answer (score 1):

I use below code in my application

```
 SqlDataSourceEnumerator sqldatasourceenumerator1 = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
            DataTable datatable1 = sqldatasourceenumerator1.GetDataSources();
            foreach (DataRow row in datatable1.Rows)
            {
                if (Environment.MachineName.Equals(row["ServerName"]))
                {

                    isSqlServerPresent = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

The only issue is, this code works on when the machine is on network, but since in my case machine will be on network, so I was ok with this issue.

It gets me the local instance of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

[How to detect SQL server instances / features installed on a machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/03/07/how-to-detect-sql-server-instances-features-installed-on-a-machine.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In fact if you want to list Servers in the network and SQL Servers instances on a machine or on the LAN, there are APIs for it.

There should be proper way to call `NetServerEnum` Windows API, for examples see:

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=107256

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/netserverenum.html